# Is there a way to format variables within an embed?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to text format a variable. By format, use discords inbuilt features like '**' for italic, '```' for block quotes, etc. I want to use these within my embed surrounding a variable.

Because of the way DJS works, your string has to be surrounded by backticks as opposed to the traditional quotation marks, this means when I try to surround my variable with other backticks for the formatting, it messes it all up.

`` `${players2}` `` is what I want to do if that makes any sense

If none of this makes sense, Im sorry.

This is the code for my embed:

````js
const e1 = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(`${server.projectName}`)
                .setColor("#228B22")
                .setDescription('> **SERVER STATUS**\n```✅ Online ```')
                .setFooter({ text: "Updates every minute" })
                .setFields(
                    { name: '> **PLAYERS**', value: `${players2}`, inline: true, },
                    { name: '> **CFX STATUS**', value: '```Operational```', inline: true},
                )
````

I want to make the variable 'players2' surrounded by ``` in order for it to be displayed in a blockquote on discord.

Answer (score 1):

````js
const e1 = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(`${server.projectName}`)
                .setColor("#228B22")
                .setDescription('> **SERVER STATUS**\n```✅ Online ```')
                .setFooter({ text: "Updates every minute" })
                .setFields(
                    { name: '> **PLAYERS**', value: "```" + player2 + "```", inline: true, },
                    { name: '> **CFX STATUS**', value: '```Operational```', inline: true},
                )
````

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the backticks:

```
`\`\`\`\n${players2}\n\`\`\``
```

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#description), or make it more readable by using normal quotes instead

````
"```\n" + players2.toString() + "\n```"
````